# MCPCB What is Tc point?

Tags: led, pcb

I have a question about the Tc point on an aluminum PCB, here is an example:

[image]

How is this point? Is it a silkscreen? Or is it something else? I imagine it is simply used to spot for a temperature measurement? So it must be placed at most near SMD LED? is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The letters Tc are printed in silkscreen. It's hard to tell from the picture whether the spot next to them is a hole, exposed copper, or something else. It's probably not silkscreen, though.

Tc here likely stands for "**t**emperature (**c**ase)" (though it could also be "**t**hermo**c**ouple" or "**t**emperature **c**heck"), seemingly designed as a test point for measuring the case temperature of the adjacent LED. Contrary to what the other answer says, I'm pretty confident it does *not* stand for temperature coefficient.

This is most likely a spot to attach a thermocouple. If it's exposed copper, the thermocouple is probably meant to be soldered* to the board for test purposes, while if it's a hole, the thermocouple is likely meant to be placed into the hole and held in place with thermally conductive epoxy. In either case, you could probably get a "good enough" measurement by just holding the thermocouple in contact with the metal just using a strong tape.

---

*Use a type T thermocouple for this, not type K--type K's chromel and alumel are both exceedingly difficult to solder to and may require unusual solder alloys, but type T's copper and constantan can be soldered easily enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a silkscreen on top of the PCB. Regarding with the meaning and the reason, I believe it stands for Temperature Coefficient, therefore the change of electrical resistance of the LED under the influence of heat. I would say that it is used for adjusting the brightness under temperature, most likely they placed this Test point near the LED to measure the temperature as you indicated so this can be correctly adjusted.

Comment: I was under the impression it stood for temperature check.

Comment: Or temperature of the case--it's definitely not temperature coefficient.

Comment: @Hearth That makes even more sense.